# Kendo Mobile: Different colors on badges

Tags: kendo-mobile

Is it possible to have badges (attached to buttons) with different colors in the same view?

My code:

```
$("#btn1").data("kendoMobileButton").badge("New");
```

Is it possible to set colors dynamically?